# No puedo instalar NetBeans en Windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2, windows10, netbeans-8.1

Comento la situación rápidamente porque no se que esta pasando, en otras máquinas con Windows 10 he podido instalar NetBeans perfectamente, inclusive en Windows 7 pero en mi PC (Windows 10) específicamente al darle doble click al instalador y dar permisos de administrador sale la barra de "Configuring installer", carga completamente, pero nunca aparece el instalador.

JDK y JRE los tengo perfectamente instalados y no me ha dado problema con otros productos de Oracle. Llevo toda la mañana cabreadísimo porque no consigo instalarlo. He probado tanto con la versión 8.0.1, la 8.1 y la 8.2 tanto en arquitecturas x86 como x64.

¿Alguno de vosotros ha pasado por la misma situación?

Comment: Con los datos de la pregunta es imposible saber el motivo. ¿No hay mensajes de error?¿te has descargado el instalador de la página oficial?¿seguro que la versión descargada es correcta (32/64)?

Comment: Si, lo he probado en otros sistemas iguales al mio, no hay mensajes de error, simplemente no dispara el instalador. El problema no es utilizarlo ya que lo pude instalar en mi otro ordenador, pero me gustaría saber el motivo porque es muy extraño, se que no hay magia en la computación, probaré a desactivar el windows defender a ver si por casualidad es eso.

Comment: Fijate que el jdk que aparece cuando estás instalando sea el 1.8 y no el 1.11, asi lo solucioné.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hola Romero!** Lo primero que te recomendaria es que descargues el instalador de x86 y que lo ejecutes normalmente.
Si el problema persiste, como esta pasando, te recomendaria que trates de realizar la instalacion a traves de la consola de windows

**Debes moverte al directorio donde tengas el instalador por ejemplo:** 
C:\Usuarios\Usuario\Downloads **luego ejecutar el instalador con la opción javahome (generalmente se instala en C:\Archivos de Programa\Java\jdk 1.6.0.45 o la ruta que tengas en tu sistema de archivos):**
C:> cd C:\Usuarios\Usuario\Downloads
C:\Usuarios\Usuario\Downloads>netbeans-8.0.2-javaee-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Archivos de Programa\Java\jdk 1.6.0.45"

*Si sigue sin funcionar lo mas probable es que sea otro problema, si persiste, trata de descargar el instalador desde otro medio.*

**Saludos y suerte!**

Recursos usados: 
[Instalacion del IDE NetBeans 8.0.1 en Windows 10](http://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_standard_edition/instalacion_del_ide_netbeans_801_en_windows_10)